# Crash caused by missing database information

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I'm currently in the process of developing a spreadsheet which fetches information from a couple different databases, however I've encountered an issue.

I have an array, which has warehouse information in it, based on company.  The warehouse array searches the access database to find orders associated with deliveries to each warehouse, however, we have warehouses in the database that have never had orders, these warehouses cause everything to crash, I'm assuming because it returns a null, but attempts to circumvent the null have ended up with different crashes or the same error (Run-time error '3021': Application-defined or object-defined error)

```
Dim CnctVastInv As String
Dim CnVastInv As New ADODB.Connection
Dim RsVastInv As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim WHCatch As String
Dim x As Long, WHInc As Long
Dim ColorProg As Long
Dim TFSwtch As Boolean

''' Connect to the database to retrieve the invoices.
CnctVastInv = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & "Persist Security Info=False;Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\ESTrading.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password = SAMvast99"
CnVastInv.Open ConnectionString:=CnctVastInv

WHInc = 3
TFSwtch = True

For i = LBound(Warehouses) To UBound(Warehouses)

    WHCatch = Warehouses(i)
    Debug.Print Warehouses(i)

    sqlstr = "SELECT tblOEInvoiceHistory.ShipCode, tblOEInvoiceHistory.SalesOrder, tblOEInvoiceFooterHistory.ProdCode, tblOEInvoiceHistory.OrderDate " & _
        "FROM tblOEInvoiceHistory " & _
        "INNER JOIN tblOEInvoiceFooterHistory ON (tblOEInvoiceHistory.SalesOrder = tblOEInvoiceFooterHistory.SalesOrder) AND (tblOEInvoiceHistory.Invoice = tblOEInvoiceFooterHistory.Invoice) " & _
        "WHERE (((tblOEInvoiceHistory.ShipCode) = " & Chr(34) & WHCatch & Chr(34) & "))" & _
        "ORDER BY tblOEInvoiceHistory.OrderDate DESC"

    RsVastInv.Open sqlstr, CnVastInv, adOpenDynamic, adLockReadOnly

    ''' Problem:  Program crashes here if a Warehouse has never ordered something.

    x = 1
    Do Until ws.Cells(x, 1) = "END"
        RsVastInv.MoveFirst
        Do While Not RsVastInv.EOF

            If TFSwtch = True Then
                ColorProg = RGB(255, 225, 0)
            Else
                ColorProg = RGB(0, 210, 225)
            End If

            If RsVastInv.Fields("ProdCode").Value = ws.Cells(x, 1) Then
                ws.Cells(x, WHInc) = RsVastInv.Fields("OrderDate")
                Select Case ws.Cells(x, WHInc).Value
                    Case (Date - 365) To Date
                        ws.Cells(x, WHInc + 1) = "X"
                        ws.Cells(x, WHInc + 1).Font.Color = vbBlack
                        ws.Cells(x, WHInc) = ""
                        ws.Cells(x, WHInc).Interior.Color = ColorProg
                    Case (Date - 730) To (Date - 365)
                        ws.Cells(x, WHInc + 2) = ws.Cells(x, WHInc).Value
                        ws.Cells(x, WHInc + 2).Font.Color = vbBlack
                        ws.Cells(x, WHInc) = ""
                        ws.Cells(x, WHInc).Interior.Color = ColorProg
                    Case Is < (Date - 730)
                        'ws.Cells(x, WHInc + 2) = ws.Cells(x, WHInc).Value
                        ws.Cells(x, WHInc) = ""
                        ws.Cells(x, WHInc).Interior.Color = ColorProg
                End Select

                Exit Do
            End If

            RsVastInv.MoveNext

        Loop

        x = x + 1

    Loop

    WHInc = WHInc + 3

    If Not UBound(Warehouses) Then
        Select Case TFSwtch
            Case Is = True
                TFSwtch = False
            Case Is = False
                TFSwtch = True
        End Select
    End If

    RsVastInv.Close

Next i
```

Comment: Test for `RsVastInv.EOF` - if True, there are no matching records.  It would help to show a little more of your code, and to indicate exactly which line gives the error.

Comment: Edited code to add more information.  I'm 90% sure that the error comes from it returning an EOF when it searches for the warehouse, but attempts to skip to the next warehouse, just cause the same crash.

Comment: How can we reproduce this issue? What does the debugger tell you if you step through the code? You can use OutputDebugStr to write messages for each warehouse to find out what value makes it crash, and then set a breakpoint on that value to step through and find out why it's dying. It's impossible for us to debug it for you, as clearly we don't have access to your data.

Comment: It's returning the error on: Do While Not RsVastInv.EOF - It's not finding records for certain warehouses, so immediately going into the loop it fails due to it showing EOF.  The problem I'm having is that I'm drawing a blank as to how to work around this.  I tried to do an If EOF it ends the DO so it moves on to the next file, but that causes the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I'm a moron.  You can't MoveFirst when a record returns EOF as True.

Final edit for fix, should have thought of this, but checking if both BOF and EOF are true at the same time was what cleared the issues with getting empty database entries.

```
x = 2
Do Until ws.Cells(x, 1) = "END"        
    If RsVastInv.BOF And RsVastInv.EOF Then Exit Do  

    RsVastInv.MoveFirst      
    Do While Not RsVastInv.EOF
```